# My personal access token is only cached for a limited amount of time and passwords will be depreciated, am I therefore expected to memorize my token?

Tags: git, authentication, github, command-line, passwords

I like to push to my GitHub repository with Git via the Command Line. GitHub has recently been nagging me to switch to using Personal Access Tokens rather than passwords. I have done so today, along with [switching my remote stuff to HTTPS](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-ssh-to-https), but the impression that I'm getting from their documentation is that [my token will only be cached for a limited amount of time, on the order of 15 minutes,](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) and that [passwords will soon be depreciated](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/about-authentication-to-github#authenticating-with-the-command-line). Does this mean that I'm expected to memorize my token, which is a long string of characters that I'm not allowed to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not expected to memorize it.  There are two solutions you can use in this case.

First, you can use a credential helper.  There are several to choose from, and typically you use either `wincred` or `manager` on Windows, `osxkeychain` on macOS, and `libsecret` on Linux and Unix (although you may have to compile it first if your distro doesn't ship it).  There's also `store`, which works on any system, but stores your password in plain text, unlike the others, which store it encrypted.

You can also use SSH with a key for pushing and pulling instead of HTTPS, which is also secure and should continue to work.  The recommendation is to use an Ed25519 key, which you can create with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and then upload to your account in GitHub.